# Preventing double execution. PHP financial app

Tags: php, security, data-integrity

If I have a script that decreases a users balance in a double entry book keeping system, and a malicious user decides to execute this script on his account on two different machines (or the same machine) at EXACTLY the same time, the whole thing would run twice right? SO heres my over simplified hypothetical scenario.

```php
    $balance = $user->ledger->getBalance(); // returns 5000
    $amount = 3000;
    if ($amount <= $balance) {
        $user->ledger->decrease($amount);
    }

    echo $user->ledger->getBalance(); // echo's 2000
```

If the script is run one after the other, the second execution will fail because there is only 2000 left in the account and it tried to decrease by 3000.

If the scripts are run simultaneously at exactly the same time, won't both balances be 5000, and both script executions deduct 3000, leaving a negative value in the ledger?

How would you prevent such a thing happening? It is vitally important to maintain the data integrity in this database table.

Comment: lock row, check row, do math on row, unlock row

Comment: Database transactions then? As simple as that? That'd be great if it is. I was concerned it would require other integrity checks that I wasn't sure about.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Comment: In a way this has simply confirmed and negated my anxiety over this code. I don't trust my own research to assume that this is all it took to keep the records safe!

Comment: there is locking with out transactions, and various locking types, but yeah you get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're talking about [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) and they're *extremely* important to eliminate in financial code.

Anything that follows a get/test/set pattern is going to have huge problems. You can't do that.

Instead take the set/test/fail pattern. Try and deduct using an atomic SQL statement such as a single operation or a transaction block. If that pushes the balance negative roll it back.

For example, this is **bad**:

```
balance = query("SELECT balance FROM accounts WHERE account_id=?")
balance -= amount
balance = query("UPDATE accounts SET balance=?")
```

Anything could happen between the fetch and write.

Instead you could do this where this query either succeeds or fails, it can't be interrupted:

```
query("UPDATE accounts SET balance=balance-? WHERE account_id=? AND balance>?")
```

That query won't run unless there's enough balance remaining. You'll get zero rows modified as a result.

You can also do this with double-ledger style book-keeping by attempting to insert the required accounting transaction rows, then check the `SUM()` to ensure that a zero or positive balance results for the originating account. If it doesn't, abandon the transaction with a `ROLLBACK`. No changes are applied.

There's a lot of ways of structuring those `INSERT` statements to make it impossible for a negative balance to occur, like `INSERT INTO x SELECT ... FROM y` where you can apply conditions to the subquery to return zero rows in the case of an insufficient balance.

Comment: Nice comprehensive answer :) I had this in my head, at least a rough approximation of it with transactions, but honestly needed some confirmation of my decision. I like the `INSERT INTO x SELECT ... FROM y` approach too, but I do have access to transactions so that'll be the way to go!

Comment: @simonw16 if you cannot reasonably contain the necessary logic into a single query you should really be using a formal transaction and [`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) to lock the necessary rows for the duration of the transaction.

Comment: @Sammitch The usual caveats of locks apply here. If your code dies in an inconvenient place and doesn't release the lock then you can create a huge mess. Always test this code under load before going live.

Comment: @tadman IIRC if the connection is lost in the middle of a connection it's an implicit rollback. Your code would have to die in a particularly unpleasant fashion and hold the connection open to result in such a situation. Even then I would say that that is a preferable outcome compared to inadvertently duplicating or destroying currency.

Comment: as its a double-entry book-keeping system we don't update. Infact we have triggers to prevent UPDATE and DELETE allowing only INSERT. Can these be locked in the same way, or will it lock the entire table. Does that mean concurrent users will have to wait until transactional user has finished...transacting?

Comment: @simonw16 Oof. So you've essentially just got a table that represents a ledger of credit and debit transactions? My suggestion would be to lock the entire ledger table and any associated balance rows for the duration of the SQL transaction. But probably the more advisable thing to do would be consult a resource specific to the design of finance systems whether that be a book, an established open source project, or a person.

Comment: @Sammitch Hmmm, yea thats my concern. Locking the entire table in a system which needs to scale for a few thousand users. Concurrently a few hundred. That could cause problems too. I wonder how this is achieved still. I could grab a book off of Amazon I suppose.

Comment: @simonw I don&#39;t think you can scale an electronic ledger for the same reason that you can&#39;t have more than one person writing in a paper ledger. There are strict constraints on the order of operations that cannot be multiplexed.

Comment: Then maybe a non-transactional way to lock. Perhaps what @tadman says with the update query.